# NodeJS Express catch-all route firing after previous route

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware

I have a basic express setup that includes the following:

```
app.all('/api/:controller/:id?', [ api, response.success, response.error ])

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('This should only fire when no route matched')
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(pubRoot, 'index.html'))
})
```

In the code for the middleware on the first route the `api` module simply resolves a promise at this point (or rejects on `404`) and then calls `next`, this makes it into the response middleware which looks like this:

```
const response = {
  success: (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).send(res.data)
  },
  error: (error, req, res, next) => {
    const statusCode = error.statusCode || 500
    res.status(statusCode).send(error.message || 'Internal Server Error')
  }
}
```

This works fine on a successful request and I get the data (and status code `200`) back. It also works on error (returning `404` and `Not Found` as expected), however, it continues on to the wildcard route. I get the `console.log` along with `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

---

UPDATE: Below is the code for the `api` module:

```
const api = (req, res, next) => {
  const controller = req.params.controller
  const event = { body: req.body, id: req.params.id, query: req.query }
  // Handle non-existent controller
  if (!controllers[controller]) {
    next(new HTTPError(404))
    return
  }
  // Controller found, process
  controllers[controller][req.method.toLowerCase()](event)
    .then((result) => {
      res.data = result
      next()
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      next(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: The code seems ok, maybe other thing can be firing the wildcard route, like a missing favicon

Comment: That's what I first thought, but I'm hitting it with Postman/cURL, and on top of that it only happens with error conditions.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem as well - did you figure out what the fix is?